# mongodb wrong when i try to findandmodify

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

this is the structure in mongodb

```
{   code:'ACBD5588',
    email:'owner@mail.com',
    object{
        array_doc:[//many documents with this structure
        {
            code_doc:'ANCB7894',
            info_doc:'....',
            //etc
        }
        ],
        counting:45,
    }
}
```

im trying to delete a document inside an array, this document haas a unique code_array so in the array there are many documents with a unique code_array, i want to erase the document inside the array

```
db.collection('database').findAndModify(
        {
            'code':code,
            'email':email,
        },[],{$pull:{'object.array_doc':{'code_doc':code_doc}}},function(err,resultado)
        {
```

but the operation gives me this error

```
uncaught exception: findAndModifyFailed failed: { "errmsg" :
 "need remove or update", "ok" : 0 }
```

Comment: please provide a sample document that you expect this to succeed on - it's not clear from the post exactly what the schema is.

Comment: each document have an array of documents named 'object', and i have to pull and push documents inside

Comment: The document you listed is not legal JSON. Do you just have extra {} on some of the fields by mistake? Also, I don't see a field named code_array, but I do see code_doc - do you have a typo in your query?

Comment: yes sry my mistake, i edit the post... now is correct, what is the mean of"The document you listed is not legal JSON."...

Comment: This works fine if I run it as a mongoskin program.  Are you running this in the shell or as a mongoskin program?

Comment: mongoskin program in nodejs expressjs

Comment: Is mongoskin up to date?  `npm ls mongoskin` should show 0.5.0.

Comment: yes of course... i check that three times

Comment: it's not syntactically legal. You had extra {}s and you don't have : between object and { - can you cut-n-paste what is actually in your program?  Also make sure all the variables are set.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MongoDB are you using? In the latest version MongoDB expects "update" or "remove" to be mentioned explicitly in the findAndModify command. Please use the following query instead.

```
db.collectionName.findAndModify({
  query : {
    'code':code,
    'email':email
  },
  update: {
     $pull : {'object.array_doc':{'code_doc':code_doc} }
  }
})
```